# Licensing Around Apps

Tags: managed-package, salesforce1-app, appexchange, licenses

Here is a scenario and I would like to know how Salesforce licensing works.

1. Client doesn't want to use any Salesforce product (CRM/Sales Cloud etc), except an app from app exchange.
2. How the licensing will work and what will be cost?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps on the AppExchange are ISV apps, so you must have a Salesforce license before you can install and use these apps. Some developers also have an OEM model, which would be purchasable directly from their website or by contacting their Sales department. Being an OEM developer has slightly more cost and has significant restrictions compared to being an ISV, so most developers either can't or won't be able to be an OEM partner. The only way to know for sure would be to contact the developers directly. If they do have an OEM model, the developers set the pricing matrix, and salesforce.com simply collects a portion of those licensing costs in exchange.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. How much costly it's to become OEM partner? Actually, I would be the developer making the product, so wanted to know the cost.

Thanks.

Comment: @itsaboutcode you need to meet minimum qualifications, which only costs a few hundred dollars, initial security review, which is a few thousand dollars, and 25% or so if whatever licensing fees you collect for your app. It's a pretty sweet deal, actually.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is covered by the 'OEM' license type. @SFDCFox provided a great explanation here:

[Difference between ISVforce and OEM Embedded App](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342373/difference-between-isvforce-and-oem-embedded-app)

The cost is determined by the app provider. They will need to negotiate with Salesforce on what pricing is allowed. Also not all kinds of apps will be allowed as OEM app, e.g. if you build a CRM app, that will not be allowed on the AppExchange (because you will be a competitor to Salesforce).